# Play splash movie every time app launch (with multi-task support)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

the app I'm working on supports iOS multi-task feature by default, and I want to stick with this.

Upon app launch, a splash movie clip is played (code is in AppDelegate), after user hits the home button, and re-launches the app, I want to the same splash movie be played before showing the last view where use was.

I know by switching off the multi-task support, I can achieve this, but in the meanwhile, I'm losing the multi-task support feature, and I need to write code to save/resume user states. So, is there any workaround for this? thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us anything about what you've already tried and why that didn't work as you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method but quite frankly I'd consider this to be user hostile behaviour. Who wants to see a movie every time they switch between apps? The point of multitasking on the iPhone  is to *quickly* change between apps and this violates that.

Comment: thanks for the hint, it's actually a request from my client. Yeah I wouldn't do this if it was my own app, but client project is client project, they own everything